# Cannot install MS Office updates

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I have Office 365 on Windows 10. When "Office updates are available" icon pops up in the System Tray and I click on it, nothing happens. The following event appears in Even Viewer -> Administrative Events:

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}
>    and APPID 
>   {316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}
>    to the user *[my_computer_name\my_user_name]* SID (S-1-5-21-1220442700-3689682443-2787758636-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.18362.449_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy SID (S-1-15-2-155514346-2573954481-755741238-1654018636-1233331829-3075935687-2861478708). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

I followed [this article](https://www.itexperience.net/2018/12/02/event-id-10016-fix-the-application-specific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permission-for-the-com-server-application-with-clsid/) (also found a number of similar articles suggesting to do the same thing), but it did not change anything.

Comment: This log does not seem to be related to Office 365 updates. According to [DCOM event ID 10016 is logged in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022522/dcom-event-id-10016-is-logged-in-windows), These 10016 events are recorded when Microsoft components tries to access DCOM components without the required permissions. In this case, this is expected and by design. These events can be safely ignored because they do not adversely affect functionality and are by design. This is the recommend action for these events.

Answer (score 1):

According to [End-user update notifications for Office 365 ProPlus](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/end-user-update-notifications-for-office-365-proplus#notifications-your-users-see-when-updates-cant-be-applied-for-several-days-to-office-365-proplus):

> After updates are downloaded to the computer that is running Office 365 ProPlus, Office attempts to apply the updates. If, after four days, the updates still aren't applied, a message appears in the notification area in Windows, telling the user that updates are available.

[image: Office updates are available]

> The message disappears in a few seconds, but the Office icon stays visible in the notification area. If the user clicks the message, Office tries to apply the updates. If any Office programs are currently being used, they must be closed.
>
> If, after six days, the updates still aren't applied, a message appears in any newly opened Office document, reminding the user that updates are available.

[image: Updates are available, but are blocked by one or more apps.]

> Users can choose Update now to apply the updates. The user is then prompted to close all open Office programs. After the updates are applied, the message disappears.
>
> Users also see notifications if they go to **File > Account** in an Office program. The Office Updates section turns yellow if updates are ready to be applied.

Here is a similar thread in TechNet Office Forum for your reference: [Office updates are available](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/449e5f4e-2204-477d-9873-89e7380491e1/office-updates-are-available?forum=officeitpro). It's just a notification. You can manually apply update your Office 365 in any Office application.

Comment: thanks for detailed reply. Yes I sometimes see the yellow bar with "Update now" button, an when I click on it the Office does update. But I would also like to be able to update by clicking the icon in the System Tray. You said that the message in the event log is not related to my problem, but I'm pretty sure it is. I refresh the log, then click on the icon in System Tray, then refresh the log again - and I see one new message. After that no more messages appear if I click the icon again.

Comment: If I kill the process behind the icon via Task Manager, then start it again manually from command prompt, then after 1st click on the icon I get another event in Event Viewer.